# Can I pass data through a new Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

In my Android app, I start a new activity with `startActivityForResult()`. I get the result in `onActivityResult()` perfectly. My problem is that there is a small bit of data that I know before I start the activity and I need that value to be available in `onActivityResult()`, too. I tried attaching it to my intent as an extra, but it wasn't attached to the intent that is available when the activity returns the result. I made it work by storing the data in a global variable, but I really don't like that approach. Is there a better, right way to pass data through an activity (instead of just to it)?

Comment: Not sure if you still have this problem, but how much data do you need to save? If it is a non-negative int it can be passed as the requestCode in startActivityForResuilt.

Comment: The value that I need to pass through is a very small integer (1-12). I embedded the value into my requestCode (MY_REQUEST * 100 + value) for my call to startActivityForResult(). Then I could get the two parts out again in onActivityResult(). That seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: sargas, I'd like to mark an answer as the correct one here, but the final, working answer is in the comments of the original question. Does SO allow you to answer a question multiple times? Can you post an answer that talks about using the request code so that I can mark it and make it the official answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the requestCode as a way to send that data as suggested in the comments looks a bit like hack to me. This is not the intended use of that code, and in general using things in this manner means you'll end up in trouble later.

Why not just define your integer in your class, and save it there?
Pseudocode:

```
class YourAcrivity extends Activity{
   private int yourInt;

   private function yourFunction(){
       //set your int
       yourInt = 11;
       //call your activity
       //startActivityForResult();
   }

  function onActivityResult(){
     //use yourInt
  }





}
```

Comment: You're right, this approach is the cleanest since I don't have to do strange things to the Request Code value. I was hoping to avoid this approach since the value I need is set in yourFunction() and then read in onActivityResult(). Outside of those two functions it has no meaning at all. I didn't want to keep around a class variable that isn't supposed to be used by the rest of the class's functions. If there are no other options, then this is the way I'll handle it in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setResult(int,Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) to give data back to onActivityResult(), passing in the same intent you were given (although some of it's properties, like the action or uri, will be useless).

You can use this to build up data between two activities, with one supplying the information it knows about and the other filing in the rest and returning when it is called.

Comment: The Activity that I'm calling is a standard Android one (shows the contact list so the user can select one). Is there a way to do this with Activities I didn't create?

Comment: @Daedylus, Ofcourse! :) It's the same way as sargas mentions:)

Comment: Where in my code should I put the call to setResult()? I think I know how to use setResult() for an Activity that I created, but how do I do it with one I didn't write?

Comment: I'm not sure what st0le means, when I first answered this I didn't realize about the called activity being one you didn't create. Not sure how this would apply, but I'm glad using the requestcode worked for ya